# Magento 2 : How to make product image zoom on mouse over

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.3, gallery-image

I want to zoom product gallery image on mouse over in magento 2.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify what you trying to achive ? If possible please add more details so that I can help you.

Comment: the question was asked 5 months ago, have you found the solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can enable on view.xml

> app/design/frontend/Package/theme/etc/view.xml

```
<var name="magnifier">
        <var name="fullscreenzoom">20</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
        <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
        <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
        <var name="width">400</var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
        <var name="height">400</var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
        <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
        <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

Comment: How to add border line for magnifier ?

Comment: where to add border?

Comment: Is this works for both desktop and mobile views?

Answer (score 0):

**Magnifier widget used for zooming the product images on product pages.**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery_mg.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension. It is a good one. 
https://store.ibnab.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-quick-cloud-zoom.html